# Python Regex selecting first option

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have the following regex that looks for the string **191(x)(y) and (z)** and combinations of this (for example - **191(x) , 191(x) and (z)**.

My regular expression is:

```
(191?(?:\w|\(.{0,3}\)(?:( (and)?|-)*)){0,5})
```

See [the regex demo](https://pythex.org/?regex=(191%3F(%3F%3A%5Cw%7C%5C(.%7B0%2C3%7D%5C)(%3F%3A(%20(and)%3F%7C-)*))%7B0%2C5%7D)&test_string=191%0A191(a)(b)(c)%0A191Transit%0Ab%20191%0A191(x)(y)%20and%20(z)&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

This expression works for the most part I need help with the following (which I can't figure out):

- While I do get 5 matches, there are 3 groups, I need to limit the result to only the first group.
- If I have the text: '191Transit', the regex should only match 191 and ignore the word 'Transit'. in this case it's 'Transit' in other examples this could be any word e.g: 191Bob, 191Smith

**I am using Python 3.6**.

Comment: Why are you looking for `\w` after `191`? Remove that and your regex works as expected https://regex101.com/r/y8wO79/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
191?(?:\([^()]{0,3}\)(?: (?:and)?|-)*){0,5}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oOWFJY/3)

**Details**

- Replace `.{0,3}` to `[^()]{0,3}` to stay within parentheses
- Remove one group around `( (?:and)?|-)*` as it's redundant
- Change the groups to non-capturing, i.e. `(...)` to `(?:...)`
- Remove `\w` alternative, it matches any word char and thus matches 0 to 5 first letters/digits/underscores after `191`